# How to reduce microbundle-crl building time?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm-package, building, microbundle

My microbundle-crl building time take more than 35 minutes. Do I can reduce the building time?

My build command is bellow:

```
microbundle-crl --minify --no-compress --format modern,cjs
```

My tsconfig.json is bellow

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "outDir": "dist",
 "target": "esnext",
 "module": "esnext",
 "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
 "skipLibCheck": true,
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "jsx": "react",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "declaration": true,
 "esModuleInterop": true,
 "noImplicitReturns": true,
 "noImplicitThis": true,
 "noImplicitAny": true,
 "baseUrl": "./src",
 "strictNullChecks": true,
 "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
 "noUnusedLocals": true,
 "noUnusedParameters": true,
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "incremental": true
},
"include": ["src"],
"exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "example", "src/assets"]
}
```

This is my building time. It takes too much time :(
How can I reduce the building time?

[image]